# Set up 301 redirects from old classic ASP pages to new ASP.NET webforms pages

Tags: asp.net, redirect, asp-classic, http-status-code-301

I've finished developing a website using ASP.NET Webforms and to finish it off I'm in the process of setting up some 301 redirects to ensure the old site's links are redirected properly.

However, the old website was written in classic ASP. What is the best way to set up redirects from old .asp pages to new .aspx pages? (Note: I don't have control over the server the website is being hosted on so I can't do anything in IIS)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just place this at the top of your page before any output:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.example.com/new-url"
%>
```

Don't put any `response.redirects` below this code.

Answer (score 12):

Simple add at the beginning of your asp pages the move command:

```
<%
   Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
   Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.example.com/newpage.aspx"
   Response.End
%>
```

This is the idea, now if you have one to one rename, and only the aspx change, you can make a simple asp script that read the currency page and make the final redirect string.

Answer (score 2):

As a sub if anyone wants

```
sub RedirectPermanently(url)
    Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
    Response.AddHeader "Location",url
    Response.End
end sub
```